# Can I write a print style just for firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing, media-queries

I have some problems with a website layout when printing with firefox.
I did some researching and found this for addressing firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
```

So I tried combining it with the media query like this, but it didn't work.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    @media print {  
        .someclass {
             color: red;
         }
    }
}
```

And this didn't work either

```
@media print {
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {   
        .someclass {
             color: red;
         }
    }
}
```

The @-moz-document url-prefix() alone works just fine.

Did I do something wrong there or is it just a stupid approach to begin with? Is there another way?
I have all my styles in the head tag for now.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you. It will only add the print style if you're on firefox.

NOTE: You'll need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if ( $.browser.mozilla == true ) { 
        $('head').append(' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">');
    }
</script>
```